# Rule for d{motion} for different motions

Tags: vim

Given:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   _   <---Cursor position
```

`3w` leads to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         _   <---Cursor position
```

and `d3w` leads to

```
fori = 0; i < 10; i++){
   _   <---Cursor position
```

i.e., even though motion `3w` takes cursor upto `i`, `i` itself is not deleted.

On the other hand, given:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   _   <---Cursor position
```

`%` leads to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                           _   <---Cursor position
```

and `d%` leads to

```
for{
   _   <---Cursor position
```

i.e., motion `%` takes cursor upto `)` and `)` itself is deleted.

So, why is there two different effects of `d{motion}`? Is there any single general rule of which both of these are consistent special cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a logic to that. In Vim, some motions such as `w` are ["exclusive"](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#exclusive), while other motions such as `%` are "inclusive". This will determine whether the action will affect the last character of the motion or not.

You can actually override the "exclusive" or "inclusive" status of a motion by using the [`v`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#o_v) operator (note that `v` is being used as an operator here, not starting Visual mode as it does when used as a Normal mode command!) So `dv3w` (or `d3vw`) will delete up to the beginning of third word "inclusive" of the character it lands on, while `dv%` will delete up to the next matching bracket "exclusive".

In a way, Visual mode is somewhat similar, since a Visual selection is "inclusive" by default, so `v3wd` would behave similarly to `dv3w`. (Though this can be overridden by the [`'selection'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27selection%27) option.)

See:

- `:help w`
- `:help %`
- `:help exclusive` (same as `:help inclusive`)
- `:help o_v`
- `:help 'selection'`

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, `v` operator flips the usual behavior, but this requires one to know the usual behavior whether it is inclusive or exclusive. Is there a way to force inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Well, Visual mode typically forces "inclusive", unless that `'selection'` option was touched... But once you get used to the way motions work, it's not hard to guess whether one will be exclusive or inclusive. The `:help` is also always very explicit about whether a motion is inclusive or exclusive.